# Could not find entity for dockerfile/elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, docker, logstash

Im new to Docker and im having an issue.

Im trying to start the [pblittle/docker-logstash](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/pblittle/docker-logstash/) container using this command:

```
sudo docker run -d -e LOGSTASH_CONFIG_URL=pathtomyconfig --link dockerfile/elasticsearch:es -p 9292:9292 -p 9200:9200 pblittle/docker-logstash
```

and i am getting the following error:

```
Error: Could not find entity for dockerfile/elasticsearch
```

If i do `sudo docker ps` is get the following:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                             COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                            NAMES
0021bd567d95        dockerfile/elasticsearch:latest   /elasticsearch/bin/e   7 minutes ago       Up 7 minutes        0.0.0.0:9200->9200/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9300->9300/tcp   cranky_meitner2
e900cbb758a5        dockerfile/redis:latest           redis-server /etc/re   12 hours ago        Up 7 minutes        0.0.0.0:6379->6379/tcp                           redis
592a4f8d97f2        dockerfile/redis:latest           redis-server /etc/re   12 hours ago        Up 7 minutes        6379/tcp                                         cocky_thompson4
```

What the devil am i doing wrong? How can i work out what is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got the value for the `--link` option wrong. The [--link](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#run) option of the `docker run` command takes a **container name or id** as value followed by `:` followed by an alias (which can be whatever you want).

What you did wrong with `--link dockerfile/elasticsearch:es` is to pass in a Docker image name instead of a docker container name/id.

Firstly you need a running container for ElasticSearch:

```
sudo docker run -d -p 9300:9300 --name myelasticsearch dockerfile/elasticsearch
```

Then you can run your logstash container linking to the container named `myelasticsearch`:

```
sudo docker run -d -e LOGSTASH_CONFIG_URL=pathtomyconfig --link myelasticsearch:es -p 9292:9292 -p 9200:9200 pblittle/docker-logstash
```